# Classification of yoga in Hinduism

Tags: scripture, yoga, classification

Is there any classification in Yoga?

If yes, what are the **names** of different types of yogas along with further classifications?

Answer (score 4):

Srimad -Bhagavad-Gita mentions eighteen types of yoga, each chapter describing one, while generally the four types given in bold are recognised by most.

· Chapter 1: Visada Yoga

· Chapter 2: Sankhya Yoga

· Chapter 3: **Karma Yoga**

· Chapter 4: **Jnana Yoga**

· Chapter 5: Karma Vairagya Yoga

· Chapter 6: Abhyasa yoga

· Chapter 7: Paramahamsa Vijnana Yoga

. Chapter 8: Akshara-Brahma Yoga

. Chapter 9: **Raja Yoga**

· Chapter 10: Vibhuti-Vistara-Yoga

· Chapter 11: Visvarupadarshana Yoga

· Chapter 12: **Bhakti Yoga**

· Chapter 13: Ksetra-Ksetrajna Vibhaga Yoga

· Chapter 14: Gunatraya-Vibhaga Yoga

. Chapter 15: Purushottama Yoga

. Chapter 16 : Daivasurasampattibhivaga Yoga

Chapter 17 : Sraddhatrayavibhaga Yoga

· Chapter 18: Moksa-Upadesa Yoga

Reference : https://medium.com/@artoflivingglobal/summary-of-18-chapter-of-bhagavad-gita-6e3a5d8c6298

Swami Vivekananda in His Complete Works only the four : Reference : https://advaitaashrama.org/cw/content.php

**Hatha** Yoga is another one, though some think its a part of the Raja-yoga.Reference:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatha_yoga

**Kriya** Yoga was introduced by Sri Shyamacharan Lahiri.Its also thought as part of Raja-Yoga/ Hatha-yoga, Reference : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriya_Yoga