# Question on Patanjali Yoga Sutras

Tags: upanishads, yoga, yoga-sutras, patanjali

*Dear Friends, I am going to study Patanjali Yoga Sutra after some days but before that, ***I want to check it's authenticity because in this [Video](https://youtu.be/AwyuWeqAA2g) , the Acharya ji,  who have very good knowledge about Upanoshads says something which seems to be against those Practices which is called meditation****  and ***Patanjali yog Sutra also talk about similar practices related to meditation; so for that purpose, I have asked three Questions given below*** :

****Question 01****: Does Patanjali Yoga Sutras come under Upanishads?

****Question 02****: Does Patanjali Yoga Sutras talk about Gyan Yoga, Bhakti Yoga?

****Question 03****: Is Yoga all about doing exercises or is it different kind of things?

---

Comment: Patanjali Yoga Sutras come under Darshana shastra not Upanishads. There are 6 Darshana shastras (https://www.esamskriti.com/e/SPIRITUALITY/Shad-Darshanas~-Six-Systems-of-Hindu-Philosophy-1.aspx) in Hinduism among which PYS is the scripture for the Yoga Darshan.

Comment: Real goal of Yoga is Raja Yoga but for preparing the body and mind for it Hatha Yoga (Asanas, Mudras, Bandhas etc.) is first practiced.

Comment: @Rickross , You are saying that Patanjali Yoga Sutras come under Darshana shastra not Upanishads but I have read somewhere that **All yog, Upnishad, Vedanth comes under Darshan Shastra  **"..... is this statement  true? ...... I am asking this because from your statement it seems like darshan shastra and upnishad are both totally different things

Comment: Yes that statement is just a loosely made one and not true in the strict sense. Upanishads are traditionally considered as part of Vedas and PYS fall under Darshana Shastras (one among the 6 mentioned)

Comment: You can go through http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Overview_Of_Scriptures

Comment: @Rickross     What is meaning of "PYS" here?

Comment: PYS is the short form of Patanjali Yoga Sutras .. too lazy to type the whole thing :D

Comment: Yoga is about union of individual being with Supreme being Purusha. It's not about excercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are six main philosophies known as *ṣaḍ-darśanas*, under the umbrella of what we refer to in the modern times as Hinduism aka the Sanatan Dharma.

The Ultimate aim of all these philosophies, which are Astika (uphold Vedas as the Supreme) is to understand and explain the nature of Ultimate Reality vis-a-vis the Individual jiva and the external world, with the Supreme Goal as Moksha.

These [Six Philosophies](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/complete-works-of-swami-abhedananda/d/doc493233.html) along with their founders are tabulated as follows -

| Philosophy (Darśana) | Founder |
| --- | --- |
| Nyaya | Rishi Gautama |
| Vaisheshika | Rishi Kanad |
| Samkhya | Kapila Muni |
| Yoga | Maharshi Patanjali |
| Purva Mimamsa (Mimamasa) | Rishi Jaimini |
| Uttara Mimama [Vedanta] | Rishi Badarayana [Veda Vyasa - Krishna Dwaipayana] |

---

---

Now,

- The main founding texts of the Vedanta are Brahma Sutras, the Upaniṣads and the Srimada Bhagvada Gita, as discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19396/17833)
- The main authoritative text for Yoga Darshan is the Yoga Sutras by Maharshi Patanjali.

---

---

Therefore, to answer your questions

`Question 01: Is patanjali yog Sutra comes under Upaniṣads?`

- No. The Upaniṣads are the authoritative texts for the Vedanta Philosophy. The Patanjali's Yoga Sutras are the most authoritative text for the Yoga-darśana only.

So Yoga Sutras by Patanjali are not Upanishads.

---

---

`Question 02: Is Patanjali yog Sutra talk about Gyan yog, bhakti yog?`

The Yogic system described in the Patanjali's Yoga Sutras is said to be of the Raja Yoga variety, as Swami Sivananda discuss in [this article](https://www.dlshq.org/teachings/raja-yoga/), so I don't see how might it be called a text of Bhakti or Jñana yoga.

In any case,

- there are some sutras in the text, which might be construed as a signage to devotion/bhakti.

For instance -

[Sutra 1.23](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115484.html)

> ईश्वरप्रणिधानाद्वा ॥२३॥
>
> īśvara-praṇidhānād-vā ||23||
>
> > Concentration may also be attained through devotion to Ishwara.

[Sutra 2.1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115498.html)

> तपः स्वाध्यायेश्वरप्रणिधानानि क्रियायोगः ॥१॥
>
> tapaḥ svādhyāy-eśvarapraṇidhānāni kriyā-yogaḥ ||1||
>
> > Austerity, study, and **the dedication of the fruits of one's work to
> > God**: these are the preliminary steps toward yoga.

- Similarly, the Sutras [2.23-26](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115505.html) maybe construed to expound the jnana yoga.

---

---

`Question 03: Is yog is all about doing exercise or it is different kind of things?`

No.

There can be several definitions of the word Yoga.

##### Definition 1:

For instance, as per the Patanjali [Yoga Sutras 1.2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115475.html),

> योगश्चित्तवृत्तिनिरोधः ॥२॥
>
> yogaś-citta-vṛtti-nirodhaḥ ||2||
>
> > Yoga is the control of thought-waves in the mind

---

##### Definition 2:

Srimada Bhagvada Gita gives the path and meaning of several forms of Yoga. As discussed in [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23728/what-is-yoga-according-to-bhagavad-gita?rq=1) there are several kinds of Yoga viz.

> Karma Yoga
>
> Bhakti Yoga
>
> Jnana Yoga
>
> Kriya Yoga, etc.

Actually, as per some interpretations, Bhagvad Gita in its 18 different chapters talks about 18 different kinds of Yogas, as discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33989/17833). Nevertheless, of those generally four or five are considered the main gist as explained above.

##### Definition 3:

Yet another interesting definition is given by god Ganesha in Ganesha Gita from Ganesha  Purāṇa as follows -

> [Ganesha Gita 1.21](https://archive.org/details/GitaSangraha/page/n11/mode/1up?view=theater)
>
> शिवे विष्णौ च शक्तौ च सूर्ये मयि नराधिप । याऽभेदबुद्धिर्योगः स
> सम्यग्योगो मतो मम ॥२१ ॥
>
> > God Ganesha spoke to Vyasa - "*In my view, the real Yoga means
> > observance of a complete non-difference, and non-duality between Shiva,
> > Vishnu, Shakti, Surya and Me.*"
>
> English Translation based on Gita Press's Hindi version.

The exercises (asanas) are a step in the ladder to condition the body for Yoga.

Just performing exercises and mudras is not Yoga. Yoga can have diverse meaning, as explained above, the Ultimate aim of all those different kinds of Yogas being, attainment of Moksha. Read [this article](https://www.dlshq.org/teachings/yoga/) by Swami Sivananda, for a short primer on the concept.